# Errno 113 No route to host Pymongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have 2 server, serverA and serverB. serverA has mongodb
I want to connect from serverB to serverA using pymongo

```
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://admin:testing@<serverA_ip>:12345/testing_db")
>>> client.server_info()
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: <serverA_ip>:12345: [Errno 113] No route to host, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 64be2a678c7dce6e46c68a5f, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('<serverA_ip>', 12345) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('<serverA_ip>:12345: [Errno 113] No route to host',)>]>
```

Here is output of `netstat -tulnp` on serverA

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12345         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      156129/mongod       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52922           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::53852                :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
```

Anyone can help? I wonder if 12345 port was open on router or not.

Comment: Can you successfully `ping` from ServerB to ServerA?